# Couldn't read row 1, col -1 from CursorWindow

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, android-cursor

Im doing a simple android application where i need to access the contacts in the phone.

However my application crashes and i get this error "Couldn't read row 1, col -1 from CursorWindow "

Here is the log:

```
06-19 11:03:59.582: E/CursorWindow(7926): Failed to read row 1, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 2 rows, 29 columns.
06-19 11:03:59.611: D/AndroidRuntime(7926): Shutting down VM
06-19 11:03:59.611: W/dalvikvm(7926): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-19 11:03:59.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7926): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-19 11:03:59.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7926): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.application/com.example.application.Search}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 1, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
06-19 11:03:59.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7926):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
06-19 11:03:59.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7926):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-19 11:03:59.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7926):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-19 11:03:59.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7926):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-19 11:03:59.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7926):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-19 11:03:59.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7926):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-19 11:03:59.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7926):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-19 11:03:59.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7926):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-19 11:03:59.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7926):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-19 11:03:59.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7926):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-19 11:03:59.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7926):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-19 11:03:59.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7926):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-19 11:03:59.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7926): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 1, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
06-19 11:03:59.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7926):     at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
06-19 11:03:59.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7926):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
06-19 11:03:59.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7926):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
06-19 11:03:59.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7926):     at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
06-19 11:03:59.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7926):     at com.example.application.Search.onCreate(Search.java:33)
06-19 11:03:59.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7926):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-19 11:03:59.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7926):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-19 11:03:59.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7926):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-19 11:03:59.842: E/AndroidRuntime(7926):     ... 11 more
```

here is the code:

```
      Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);
    people.moveToFirst();
    while(people.moveToNext()) {
       int name = people.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);
       String contact = people.getString(name);

       int contact_no = people.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.NUMBER);
       String number = people.getString(contact_no);

    }

    people.close();
```

Comment: you missed peope.moveToFirst()

Comment: i had added that too. but it still gives the same problem
thus i removed it from the code for now.

Comment: there is no database im just trying to access the names and numbers of all the contacts.

Comment: just log "name" and " contact_no" and see which one is -1, ir means that column is not in the cursor

Comment: the error is occurring for the NUMBER
it works fine for the name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of pass null as projection ask for the column you need

```
 Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
 String[] projection = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};

Cursor people = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
```

Comment: the error is occurring for the NUMBER it works fine for the name

Answer (score 0):

As the exception suggests the column number is not proper. So either the column PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME or PhoneLookup.NUMBER is not present in the cursor which is returned from the query, based on in which line the exception is occurring. You can explicitly specify the columns which you need from db, so that you know if the query doesn't throw any exceptions,then the column will surely exist.